# Logging Nant Output

Tags: svn, nant, nantcontrib

I am currently using a tag to log Nant output to a log file `OUTPUT.log`.  I want to save the Nant output to a different file, depending on part of the `target`.  I currently am using:

```
<record name="C:\\Nant\Logoutput\**output.log**" level="Info" action="Start" failonerror="false" />
```

I want to be able to save the target to its own file, where the file name is equal to the target.

Examples:

With output of `<Target="abc">` save to `abc.log`
With output of `<Target="xyz">` save to `xyz.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [target::get-current-target](http://nant.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/help/functions/target.get-current-target%28%29.html) function.